# Generic array of primitives

Tags: generics, kotlin

Is it possible in Kotlin to create a generic class with type parameter T that is used to create an array of primitives? I am trying to create a column class that can be backed by a primitive array. Is it possible to do this generically in Kotlin?

```
class Foo<T>{n: Int) {

  // How to make this int[]?
  // Or IntArray?
  val data = Array<T>(n)

}
```

Comment: Don't believe so. As far as I understand it, `Array` in Kotlin is equivalent to `Object[]` in Java. Kotlin is also subject so some of the same limitations as Java, such as an incompatibility between generics and primitives. For instance, a `List<Int>` in Kotlin is really a `List<Integer>` under the hood (at least when running on the JVM).

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution I could come up with was to make the `data` a `lateinit var` of type `Any` and create an `inline fun` which would then allow the use of `reified` to create an array of type `T`.

```
class Foo<T>(val n: Int) {
    // How to make this int[]?
    // Or IntArray?
    lateinit var data: Any

    inline fun <reified T> createNullArray() {
        data = arrayOfNulls<T>(n)
    }
}
```

---

**Edit** - In case you're going to be doing that, then it wouldn't make sense to ask for generic for the class.

```
class Foo(val n: Int) {
    lateinit var data: Any
    inline fun <reified T> createNullArray() {
        data = arrayOfNulls<T>(n)
    }
}
```